# CakePHP 3 Soap Server Error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I try to create a Soap Server in CakePHP 3 but if I want to connent with my client i become error's every time.

I set up the server in a function:

```
public function view($id) {

    $connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    $user = $connection->execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='.'"'.$id.'"')->fetchAll('assoc');

    $obj = new Post;

    $this->viewBuilder()->layout = false;
    $this->autoRender = false;
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled",0); //disable wsdl cache

    $server = new SoapServer(null, array(
        'uri' => 'http://localhost/test-uri',
        'encoding'=>'UTF-8'
    )
    );

    $server->setObject($obj);
    $server->handle();  

}
```

in a model I create this function:

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\Utility\Xml;

class Post {

    function testfunktion($param){

        return $param;

    }

}
```

my client script show this:

```
$soap = new SoapClient( 
null, 
array( 
   "location" => "http://localhost/shop_system/users/view/2",
   "uri" => "http://test-uri",
   "trace" => 1
  ) 
);

try {
    $product = $soap->testfunktion("Michael");
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo $e;
    print($soap->__getLastResponse());
}
```

and this is my output:

> SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop_system\webroot\client.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\shop_system\webroot\client.php(15): SoapClient->__call('testfunktion', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\shop_system\webroot\client.php(15): SoapClient->testfunktion('Michael') #2 {main}
>   Notice (8): Undefined index: HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE [APP/Controller\UsersController.php, line 22]Michael

i dont know what i must do by this error

Comment: Start with some research on the error **http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SoapFault+exception+looks+like+we+got+no+XML+document**

Comment: Side note, `id='.'"'.$id.'"'` is an SQL injection vulnerability. **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#binding-values**

Comment: i research all stackoverflow sites but i dont find a solution

Comment: With all due respect, I kinda doubt that... however, if you tried anything, then you should point that out in your question, so that people don't waste their time giving you advices on stuff that you already tried.

Comment: i try to parse $param in xml with this $text = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<post>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Best post</title>
    <body> ... </body>
</post>';
$xml = Xml::build($text);
$xmlString = $xml->asXML();
   return $xmlString;

Comment: but with change nothing, also what i can do